# Regex to match a consecutive occurrence of two backslashes?

Tags: java, regex

I have to replace all occurrences of `'\''\'` with `'\'` in a `String`. I know regex `"\\\\"` means `\` but how do I write a regex for `replaceAll()` to match `'\''\'`. I tried:

```
 .replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\")
```

but I get a java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException?

Comment: You can either use `"\\{2}"` or `"\\\\"` regex patterns. Or even `"\\+"` to match every at least 2 consecutive occurrences of backslashes.

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist Not quite. ``\`` is special in regex and in String literal. So to write string which could represent regex matching ``\`` we need to escape it once in regex ``\\`` and once in String `"\\\\"`.

Comment: Oh. Right, forgot about it's in String in Java :)
I'm using regexes in Oracle SQL mostly, it's way more practical there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace literals instead of `replaceAll` use `replace` method which doesn't use regex syntax:

```
replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

If you absolutely must use `replaceAll` remember that its second parameter also have some special characters which are

- `$` (where `$x` represents match from group `x`)
- and `\` to escape that `$` and itself,

so code using `replaceAll` would need to look like:

```
replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\")
```

since we also need to escape `\` twice (once in regex engine `\\`, once in string `\\\\`).

Comment: I tried it and get: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1

Comment: @someone_somewhere did you remove `All` suffix from `replaceAll`?

Comment: Sorry it I had:
  validElement = validElement.replaceAll("\\\\{", "{").replace("\\\\","\\");
so it broke on the first part. 
.replace("\\\\","\\") worked :)
Thank you.